# Dimensional Modelling a scenario

Tags: ssas, dimensional-modeling

I have the following scenario which i am trying to model for a OLAP cube. I am currently using Microsoft Analysis Services.

We have many studies. A Patient always belongs to 1 study. A Patient can have 1 or many visits for a study. During a visit a patient can fill 1 or many forms. Forms are different for different studies. The same form can have different questions for different studies. A Patient fills a Central Demographics form which has information about the patient. The Central Demographics form can have different questions depending upon the study.

I have a Study Dimension, Patient Dimension, Visit Dimension and a Fact table with foreign keys to Study, Patient and Visit Dimension. The questions on the Central Demographics form are attributes for a Patient Dimension. But as these vary study to study so i am confused how would i handle them. For example Study A can have 4 questions on a Central Demographics form where as Study B can have 8 question on a Central Demographics form.

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me with the modelling for this kind of scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: That seems like an overly-broad question.  See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is the first time i am posting and i understand its more of a design question.

Comment: That notwithstanding. It will require a lot of someone's time and it is more a tutorial or book or class kind of education you're needing, not just a properly constrained technical answer.  Also see [Questions to Avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand how to utilize this site and stay within the guidelines (and get more people trying to answer your questions).

Comment: I would like to wait and see if anyone can help me out with this...

Comment: This question doesn't strike me as overly broad at all - it's asking a question about a very specific scenario and has plenty of details. It's a very fair question about how to create one single aspect of a data warehouse or data mart. I am very busy otherwise would put together an answer - if no one else has answered in the next couple of days I will try to pop back and do so myself! One question - does the Central Demographics form have a set number of questions and only some are used for each study, or are questions added to it frequently, perhaps for every new study?

Comment: Jo Douglass, thanks for your response. There is no set number of questions. It is very study specific.      This is what i was thinking of doing.
1.      Patient Dimension (related to Visit fact table)
2.      Study Dimension (related to Visit fact table)
3.      Visit Fact Table
4.   PatientDemographics Dimension (referenced) (related to Patient Dimension). The reason I am doing this way is because the central demographics had questions based on which the data will be sliced and diced. Also I am not doing a master question table because everything is study specific.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kimball](http://www.kimballgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/2013.09-Kimball-Dimensional-Modeling-Techniques11.pdf) uses the term "Multivalued Dimensions and Bridge Tables" for this. 
You would group your survey/form questions and link questions from the individual question dimension to the group via a many-to-many bridge. Here is [an MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170463.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about how to model this with SSAS. By the way, I have not yet encountered a dimensional modelling problem that Kimball has not documented a solution for.

Comment: I have been reading about it and i think have an idea what i would like to do with this situation. 
1.      Patient Dimension (related to Visit fact table)
2.      Study Dimension (related to Visit fact table)
3.      Visit Fact Table
4.   PatientDemographics Dimension (referenced) (related to Patient Dimension). The reason I am doing this way is because the central demographics had questions based on which the data will be sliced and diced. Also I am not doing a master question table because everything is study specific.

Thanks.